# Appending two columns in one text file

Tags: windows, cmd, append

How to append two columns from one text file separated by space into one text file using command window.

```
1  2    
3  4    
5  6
```

The output I want is:

```
1    
2    
3
4
5
6
```

OR just

```
1
3
5
2
4
6
```

Comment: Start with `for /F "tokens=1,2" %G in (yourfile.txt) do @echo %G -- %H`, for first look;  [see more here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). Return and [edit] your question with a code snippet for more help with your code. Or, if you do find a solution yourself, answer and accept....

Answer (score 0):

Use [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk '{ print $1; print $2 }' A.txt
```

Comment: I think you are using Windows's CMD. You might consider switching to Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

`for /f "tokens=1,*" %a in (a.txt) do @echo %a& echo %b`

if you want to redirect this output to another file.

`for /f "tokens=1,*" %a in (a.txt) do @(echo %a& echo %b)>> b.txt`